# module federation with vue3, vite and typescript not working as expected

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, micro-frontend

**My Expectation:** I do expect to be able to use `myBtn`-component in the `host-app`, however it did not work :(

**The Problem:**

In a consolation of Micro FrontEnd app, where all FrontEnds are writen in Vue 3.3.2, I assume, the the typescript compiler is not able to recognize the remotely federated module(s).

[The error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6IJc.png)

**Though, How I got there?**
Both `remote-app` and `host-app` were scafolded using `npm init vue@latest` with typescript template.

In the remote App, I have the following vite.config file

```
// remote-app


import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), federation({
    name: 'remote-app',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    exposes:{
      './myBtn': '.\\src\\components\\myButton\\myButton.vue',
    },
    shared:{
      vue:{
        generate: false
      }
    }
  })],
  server:{
    port: 5001
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build:{
    target: 'esnext',
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: 'es',
        minifyInternalExports: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then the `remote-app` was build using `npm run build` afterward was served via `vite preview --port 5001 --strictPort`.

On the other hand, the `host-app` has the following `vite.config.ts` file

```
// host-app

import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), federation({
        name: 'host-app',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes:{
          'remote_app':'http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
          },
        shared: {
          vue:{}
        }
  })],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build:{
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            minifyInternalExports: false
        }
    }  }
})
```

Also I tried in the `host-app` to configure the remote like:

```
        remotes:{
          'remote_app':{
            external:'http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js',
            externalType: 'promise',
            format: 'esm'
            }
          }
```

but unfortunately without success.

Any Idea ? thank you in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: kind of, in the host app, I add a declaration statement in the host-app like `declare module "remoteApp/MyBtn";`, so that I was able to use `MyBtn` in there.

However, I did not managed to get auto-compolete for MyBtn's properties :(